# i can`t repair this err: BITFIELD_INVALID

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require(`discord.js`)
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const nodemon = require("nodemon");
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: ["CHANNEL", "GUILD_MEMBER", "MESSAGE", "REACTION", "USER"],
});

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();

["command.handler", "event.handler"].forEach((handler) => {
  require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, Discord);
});

client.login(`my token :)`);

throw new RangeError('BITFIELD_INVALID', bit);
^
```

RangeError [BITFIELD_INVALID]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: CHANNEL.
at Function.resolve (C:\Users\swide\Desktop\NWMPoCoToAleTak\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:152:11)
at Function.resolve (C:\Users\swide\Desktop\NWMPoCoToAleTak\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:147:40)
at Client._validateOptions (C:\Users\swide\Desktop\NWMPoCoToAleTak\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:550:33)
at new Client (C:\Users\swide\Desktop\NWMPoCoToAleTak\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:76:10)
at Object. (C:\Users\swide\Desktop\NWMPoCoToAleTak\main.js:5:16)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32) {
[Symbol(code)]: 'BITFIELD_INVALID'
}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and make sure to **ask a question**. It should start with a question word like "how" or "why" and end with a question mark (`?`). When we read the post, it should be clear what task you are trying to perform with the code, specifically what things you have already tried to resolve the problem, and exactly what you need from us in order to fix the problem. Simply posting code and an error message is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your intents are not defined correctly,

`intents: ["CHANNEL", "GUILD_MEMBER", "MESSAGE", "REACTION", "USER"],`

These are not intents, these are partials.
Please visit this [page](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Intents?scrollTo=s-FLAGS) to see a list of all intents to choose from.

To correct this use this code:

```js
const { MessageEmbed, Intents } = require(`discord.js`)

const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [], // Insert intents from below, separated by a comma [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, etc.]
    partials: ["CHANNEL", "GUILD_MEMBER", "MESSAGE", "REACTION", "USER"],
});
```

Intents List:

```
Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS
Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS
Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_BANS
Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS
Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INTEGRATIONS
Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_WEBHOOKS
Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INVITES
Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES
Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES
Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS
Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING
Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES
Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS
Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING
Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_SCHEDULED_EVENTS
```

As for the other answer, you can do this to enable all intents but it may unnecessary if you don't need all intents but if you chose to, which most would advise against but it is your choice, that code would look like this (with the partials from above as well):

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: 131071,
    partials: ["CHANNEL", "GUILD_MEMBER", "MESSAGE", "REACTION", "USER"],
});
```

UPDATE intents: 32767 no longer includes all intents, all intents is now 131071

Answer (score -1):

If you want to enable all intents here's a quick way;

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: new Discord.Intents(32767) })
```

this allows all intents.